# General MySQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql

is it possible, to combine some "String"-statements in one MySQL-Query, like in the following example?

Explanations:

I created some database with tables for the various standard types like "Int", "Double" and so on.
So the tables names are "Standard_Int", "Standard_Double" etc..
In addition there are some other tables like "Key_Names", "Main" and so on.

To get more specific, I want to create some query like the following:

> insert into ... (tables name)

```
         ↑
   "Standard_" + ... (tables name)
                  ↑
   select table from Key_Names where
             → Standard_Text
             → Standard_Double
             → Standard_Int
```

In other words: I need some statement combining two strings.

Thanks for your help,
Korbi

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the `CONCAT` function:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with the first comment, use the CONCAT function in your select statement...

```
SELECT CONCAT(TableA.attribute1, TableA.attribute2)
FROM TableA...
```